# Fluid 2D shapes panning/scrolling

Tags: .net, user-interface, graph, graphics, 3d

Suppose that you have an application drawing a complex flowchart (in my case a .NET one). The user needs to navigate the flowchart with an acceptable and consistent framerate, let's say 10 FPS. This means that if the flowchart is huge, you won't be able to draw everything without blocking the UI.

In addition, the shape complexity varies considerably and you want to draw as many shapes as possible to give the user the impression that nothing is missing during dynamic movements.

The first approach I tested is the one to compute how much time I have to draw a single frame (to maintain 10 FPS) and stop drawing after hitting that threshold, obviously skipping shapes out of the screen.

The results are far from good. Without any logic on what to draw first, the drawing can stuck on a few complex shapes and skip most of the simple ones (giving the user the impression that he/she lost the chart). In addition, the estimated framerate can vary considerably and consequently the number of shapes drawn.

Do you know a better approach to follow? Do you know any article on the subject?

Thanks.

Comment: A first thing to do is to associate a bounding box to every item and use it do decide if any part of it will be visible inside the window. In a second step you can organize the boxes in a tree of nested boxes, which will allow fast rejection of groups of items. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree

Answer (score 0):

The first optimization to try is to sort your shapes from less complex to more complex then do the drawing for the time you have. This way you should skip less objects in general, which means more objects on the screen.
When the user stops moving you may run the full drawing then. I think I've noticed similar behavior in some vector drawings in PDF files.

Another way is to reuse already drawn image when possible.
You add a 2D Rectangle parameter to your drawing code and test each object if they hit the rectangle, which is used as a bounding box for your drawing.
When the user moves your flowchart, say 10 pixels to the left - you copy your current image, moving it by those 10 pixels, and draw only 10-pixel wide vertical bar on the right - this way you have much less objects to consider.
This approach is implemented in Qt 2D scene, with a lot of tricks and optimizations, making it virtually transparent for the coder. Very interesting implementation but quite hard to read :).

You may also explore threading and all posibilities it gives you:

You may just do your drawing in another thread to not to block the GUI. If the thread ends drawing an image you just show it in the window.

You may split your chart into squares/rectangles and give every square to different thread. When the view moves and new squares become visible you execute drawing for it. In the main thread you just check what is already done and copy it to destination position. Mobile Web browsers render web pages in similar way.

Depending on your exact content and preferences about how should it look like during movement you could also split the chart into some layers - more and less important etc. Then in the main thread you just blend/mix images that are ready, waiting for others.